# Rails 3.2 link_to a File in Safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, carrierwave

I have an area on my site where a user can upload files to the server.  The files are not restricted to the type of file.  Everything works in Firefox etc, but safari tries to open the file in a new window resulting in gibberish for filetypes it does not understand.  I can "save linked file" and everything works fine. However for usability I want the file to download automatically when the link is clicked.  I used carrierwave to upload the files.

Here is what My link looks like

```
<%= link_to document.name,"#{document.file}"%>
```

Comment: [Setting the content type](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#setting-the-content-type) could fix the problem.

Comment: @Stefan Can I set it the content_disposition in the actual link declaration?

Comment: No, `link_to` just generates a link. You could write your own `download_link_to` helper using the `send_file` method @gabrielhilal is mentioning.

Comment: @Stefan. your original answer fixed the problem after I realized I had a syntax error.  THe content type is correctly set.  Write your answer out if you want credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stefan answered this in the comments.

in Gemfile:

```
gem 'mime-types'
```

in the uploader file generated by carrierwave:

```
require 'carrierwave/processing/mime_types'

class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes

  process :set_content_type
end
```